# How to monitoring a server's resources/performance

Tags: amazon-ec2, resources, server, monitor

I've been giving a task to monitor an Amazon ec2 instance's resources/performance. I do not have access to the Amazon Control Panel/Dashboard but I'm allowed to install free software on the ec2 that can track the stats.
I know you need to pay for indpeth/custom charts/graphs in the Amazon Control Panel, is this maybe the best approach for accurate stats or are the preferable free software that can track the following stats.

- Total used memory and free memory in x amount time
- Total requests made in X amount time
- Total CPU usage in x amount time

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a good, basic monitoring service like [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/). They have both server and application monitoring available that, together, could give you the stats you list. Your first and third items are more server-centric, while your second bullet is specific to the application you're running (i.e. Apache, NGINX, Postfix, etc.).

[Here is a list](https://blog.profitbricks.com/top-47-cloud-server-monitoring-sysadmin-tools/) of other monitoring options.